# How to run an object method from a function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a specific task: to create an object (instance of a sub-class) within a function, call a method on that object and then return it. These are the classes:

```
// Task 1: Code a Person class
class Person {
    constructor(name = "Tom", age = 20, energy = 100) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.energy = energy;
    }
    sleep() {
        this.energy += 10;
        console.log("Energy has increased, now it's ", this.energy);
    }
    doSomethinFun() {
        this.energy -= 10
        console.log("Energy has decreased, now it's ", this.energy);
    }
}

// Task 2: Code a Worker class
class Worker extends Person {
    constructor(name, age, energy, xp = 0, hourlyWage = 10) {
        super(name, age, energy);
        this.xp = xp;
        this.hourlyWage = hourlyWage;
    }
    goToWork() {
        this.xp += 10
        console.log("XP is nov increased, now it's ", this.xp);
    }
}
```

I've tested all methods on a custom object instantiated from Worker - they all work.
Now the problem(s):

1. The task: Inside the intern function instantiate the `Worker` class to code a new intern object.
   The intern should have the following characteristics:

   - name: Bob
   - age: 21
   - energy: 110
   - xp: 0
   - hourlyWage: 10

   As I come to find out they cannot have the same name, so I figured to name the object intern1 because function name was predefined by the task.

   ```
   function intern() {
   var intern1 = new Worker("Bob", 21, 110, 0, 10);
   console.log(intern1);
   }
   ```
2. The task: Run the `goToWork()` method on the intern object. Then `return` the intern object.

   ```
   intern1.goToWork();
   return intern();
   ```

   I guessed the return is on the function which will automatically invoke the object, and so it works. However intern1.goToWork() doesn't. The console throws ReferenceError: intern1 is not defined... as I found out the problem is of scope... but I cannot find the solution. How to execute goToWork() method on intern1?

Comment: *"Inside the `intern` function instantiate the `Worker` class to code a new intern object."* I hope that's not actually what the assignment says, because "to code a new intern object" makes no sense. Is that really the text of the assignment?

Comment: *"Run the goToWork() method on the intern object. Then return the intern object."* **In** `intern` function? Or what? This is too fragmentary to make sense of. But they **may** mean `function intern() { var intern1 = new Worker("Bob", 21, 110, 0, 10); console.log(intern1); intern1.goToWork(); return intern1; }`

Comment: For clarification reason exactly I copy-pasted the actual assignment text...but what really baffled me was the nesting part (nowhere to find in the practices and instructions before this test). Ok... they spoke about scope in general and nesting functions inside functions, but not objects inside functions... and how to go about with methods from the function-nested objects.

Comment: Your suggested code works fine, just afterwards call for the functions and that's it...Thank you for support :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This works](https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-banach-8cctsd?file=/src/index.js:722-884)

```js
function intern() {
  var intern1 = new Worker("Bob", 21, 110, 0, 10);
  intern1.goToWork();
  return intern1;
  }

  const i = intern();
  console.log(i);
```

Comment: Yeah...just assign function to a variable and console.log it...simple...thanx! :)

Comment: Welcome, By the way we are not assigning the function we are calling the function & assigning it's returned value to the variable.

Answer (score 0):

the function intern() doesnt return anything and yet you returned nothing.
If i understood correnctly, you can do something like that:

```
function intern() {
    return new Worker("Bob", 21, 110, 0, 10);
}
let intern1 = intern();
intern1.goToWork();
```

Comment: The code you suggested doesn't fit the whole picture. It outputs the method but not the actual object. We need both. The function should be defining the object, and then the return of the same...thanx for your time. .